# Data subsets from multiyear timeseries data

Tags: python, dataframe, subset, permutation

I have 15 mins multiyear timeseries data (a total of 16 years) from 2007 - 2022. Data looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJ0n-hAPvtr62ZXwaVTHBhsDiRLxYyX_/edit#gid=1159949573). I want to make all possible subsets out of this data. Each subset should have one year of values. so basically it should be 4 (15 mins) x24 (hours) x 365 or 366 days(leap year) = 35,040 row data or 35,136 a for leap year.

The subset should be formed in a way that it has 12 months from different years. So for example:

Jan from 2021 (all the 15 mins from a month should come all together in the subset)
Feb from 2018
Mar from 2012
Apr from 2015
May from 2009
Jun from 2014
Jul from 2022
Aug from 2010
Sep from 2015
Oct from 2020
Nov from 2018
Dec from 2007
It's fine to have two months from same year as well.

Please help me how can I move forward.

here's my code for reading data so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns_to_read = ['DateTime', 'PLANT ENERGY MWh']

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/97150/Data - 15 mins multiyear -R2.xlsx', skiprows=0, usecols=columns_to_read)

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

df.dropna(subset=['DateTime'], inplace=True)

df['Month'] = df['DateTime'].dt.month.astype(int)
df['Year'] = df['DateTime'].dt.year.astype(int)


#df['Month'] = df['DateTime'].dt.month
#df['Year'] = df['DateTime'].dt.year

df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
```

Comment: How do you decide on which year you pick for a specific month - or is this supposed to be random? Anyways, have a look at Pandas `DataFrame.groupby` method which allows to split your data on one but also several criteria. So you an do sth. like `df.groupby(by=[df['DateTime'].dt.month, df['DateTime'].dt.year])`. Maybe that is already enough for you to keep going.

Comment: already tried that. I am not sure if that would give me different combinations. Example: It's like i have a list of 3 and then i want all the possible combinations of numbers within that list with sets of 2. Get that? In my case I am trying to make all possible combinations of monthly data within 16 years data but condition is it should be equal to 1 year of values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution, with no-frills or overcomplicated pythonic adjustments…
I'm assuming that you want to have random years in subsets, but that every couple “month + year” must be considered, and must be present in (only) one of the sub-dataset.

The result is stored in a list of 16 pandas DataFrames, and printed into a file.

Hoping is what you are looking for!
Let me know if there's something unclear, Ciao!

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
from itertools import product

# Define the columns to be read from the Excel file
columns_to_read = ['DateTime', 'PLANT ENERGY MWh']
# Read data from the Excel file into a DataFrame (path changed for me) 
df = pd.read_excel(r'./Data_15_mins_multiyear-R2.xlsx', skiprows=0,  
                  usecols=columns_to_read)

# Convert 'DateTime' column to datetime type
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
# Drop rows where 'DateTime' is missing
df.dropna(subset=['DateTime'], inplace=True)

## Define start and end dates for data filtering
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2007-01-01')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2022-12-31')
# Filter the DataFrame to include only data within the specified date range
df = df[(df['DateTime'] >= start_date) & (df['DateTime'] <= end_date)]

## Extract 'Month' and 'Year' from the 'DateTime' column
df['Month'] = df['DateTime'].dt.month
df['Year'] = df['DateTime'].dt.year
# Group the DataFrame by 'Month' and 'Year'
grouped = df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])

# Get the unique years present in the DataFrame
unique_years = df['Year'].unique()

# Create a dictionary to hold data subsets for each year
yearly_data = {}

### Populate the yearly_data dictionary with subsets of data for each year
for year in unique_years:
    subset_df = df[df['Year'] == year].reset_index(drop=True)
    yearly_data[year] = subset_df

N = len(yearly_data)

## Get all possible combinations of months and years and shuffle
all_combinations = list(product(range(1, 13), unique_years))
random.shuffle(all_combinations)

# Create an empty list to hold the final datasets
datasets_list = []

#################### Build all datasets:
for _ in range(N):
    # Create an empty DataFrame to store the current dataset
    curr_dataset = pd.DataFrame()
    
    # Loop through months 1 to 12
    for month in range(1, 13):
        # Retrieves the index from the iterable (the desired combination) 
        # according to the condition (placeholder for the useless year value)
        index_to_pop = next((i for i, (m, _) in enumerate(all_combinations) \
        if m == month), None)
        
        if index_to_pop is not None:
            # Remove the combination from the list and get the associated year
            _, year = all_combinations.pop(index_to_pop)
            
            # Get the df for the selected year
            subset_df = yearly_data[year]
            
            # Filter the subsets to include only rows with the current month
            subset_month = subset_df[subset_df['Month'] == month]
            
            ## Concatenate the subset_month df to the current one.   
            # Avoid to use "append" instead of "concat", since the former is deprecated
            curr_dataset = pd.concat([curr_dataset, subset_month], ignore_index=True)
    
    # Append the subdf to the datasets_list
    datasets_list.append(curr_dataset)

########## Print the result into a file 
## Indicate that all columns and rows must be displayed, without any truncation
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
for i, dataset in enumerate(datasets_list, start=1):
    # Write on a file in update mode
    with open('my_output_file.txt', 'a') as file: 
        print(f"SubDataset {i}:", file=file)
        print(dataset, file=file)
        print()
```

**==> OUTPUT <==**
*my_output_file* is:

```
SubDataset 1:
                 DateTime  PLANT ENERGY MWh  Month  Year
0     2013-01-01 00:07:00          0.000000      1  2013
1     2013-01-01 00:22:00          0.000000      1  2013
2     2013-01-01 00:37:00          0.000000      1  2013
3     2013-01-01 00:52:00          0.000000      1  2013
.....     .........      ........      .......... ......
34941 2022-12-30 23:22:00          0.000000     12  2022
34942 2022-12-30 23:37:00          0.000000     12  2022
34943 2022-12-30 23:52:00          0.000000     12  2022

SubDataset 2:
             DateTime  PLANT ENERGY MWh  Month  Year
0     2019-01-01 00:07:00          0.000000      1  2019
1     2019-01-01 00:22:00          0.000000      1  2019
2     2019-01-01 00:37:00          0.000000      1  2019
3     2019-01-01 00:52:00          0.000000      1  2019
4     2019-01-01 01:07:00          0.000000      1  2019
.....     .........      ........      .......... ......
20446 2014-07-31 23:37:00          0.000000      7  2014
20447 2014-07-31 23:52:00          0.000000      7  2014
20448 2015-08-01 00:07:00          0.000000      8  2015
20449 2015-08-01 00:22:00          0.000000      8  2015
20450 2015-08-01 00:37:00          0.000000      8  2015
.....     .........      ........      .......... ......
```

To quickly check the distribution of years for a month *x* in each dataset…

```py
month_x = []
x = 1
# Loop through each dataset
for dataset in datasets_list:
    # Filter rows with Month equal to x
    row_to_append = dataset.loc[dataset['Month'] == x].iloc[0]
    month_x.append(row_to_append)
```

***month_x* is:**

```
[DateTime            2013-01-01 00:07:00
 PLANT ENERGY MWh                    0.0
 Month                                 1
 Year                               2013
 Name: 0, dtype: object,
 DateTime            2019-01-01 00:07:00
 PLANT ENERGY MWh                    0.0
 Month                                 1
 Year                               2019
 Name: 0, dtype: object,
 DateTime            2018-01-01 00:07:00
 PLANT ENERGY MWh                    0.0
 Month                                 1
 Year                               2018
 Name: 0, dtype: object,
........................................
........................................
```